# Export only item with checked boxes

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to make an html export of checkboxes lists with emacs with some sort of filter.
For instance, I would like to export only the elements whose box is checked.
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this hook:

```
(add-hook 'org-export-preprocess-hook
      (lambda() (goto-char (point-min))
        (delete-non-matching-lines "\[X\]\\|")))
```

Tick some checkboxes.

Create a list with one-line items in an .org file.

<kbd>C-u C-c C-c</kbd> on the first item of this list to add empty checkboxes to all items.

Put the list in an active region and do <kbd>C-c C-e R</kbd>.

Comment: This sounds great! How could I create a switch for this behaviour (something to be able to toggle the filter)?